# Adding KnownTypeAttribute on DataContractSerializer?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I am in a WebForms, and I try to serialize an object to XML code. Well, using:

```
using (FileStream writer = new FileStream("c:/temp/file.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(videoContainer.GetType());
    ser.WriteObject(writer, videoContainer);
}
```

I got this error: *Type 'Google.GData.YouTube.YouTubeEntry' with data contract name 'YouTubeEntry:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Google.GData.YouTube' is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.*

So I tried this one:

```
IEnumerable<string> lista = new List<string>();
lista.ToList().Add("YouTubeEntry:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Google.GData.YouTube");

using (FileStream writer = new FileStream("c:/temp/file.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(videoContainer.GetType(), lista);
    ser.WriteObject(writer, videoContainer);
}
```

passing the KnownTypeAttribute list, but seems it can't get a List? :O Not sure what I should do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide a list of Types not a list of Strings

```
var lista = new List<Type>();
lista.Add(typeof(Google.GData.YouTube.YouTubeEntry));

using (FileStream writer = new FileStream("c:/temp/file.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(videoContainer.GetType(), lista);
    ser.WriteObject(writer, videoContainer);
}
```

Comment: can't do lista.Add() directly. .NET says it doesnt contain a definition of "add"? :O

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a collection of Type objects to the constructor. Not strings.

```
DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(videoContainer.GetType(), new List<Type> {typeof(YouTubeEntry)});
```